# How to keep the Highlighter tool selected in Skim?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, highlighting

When I use the highlighter how do I set it is selected by default. I don't want to have to go and click back on the highlight icon each time.
I have made a shortcut but I have to press shortcut key after every selection.

Answer (score 2):

You can select highlight as your main tool:
[image: screenshot]

You can click and hold the rightmost tool to have "highlight" as one of the default tools.

This lets you highlight by default, and you shouldn't need to select highlight every time.